# THREE.JS - Change Loaded Mesh's Vertex Coordinate Absolutely (Distort Mesh) and Use That Vertex

Tags: three.js

I want to change my loaded mesh's vertices in absolute way. For example, this is a vertex from original mesh (loaded mesh):
[original vertex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWKA2.png)

That vertex has to be like this:
[changed vertex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93o9H.png)

As you can see y coordinate changed (specifically y), but there is a problem.
I cannot see that on viewport and use for positioning.
In other word, I want to distort my mesh by changing vertex coordinate values, after distortion process I want to make manipulation on it.

To do that I used this:
[codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDqAI.png)
, so I made y coordinate subtracted with 5.5;

console.log(vector) shows expected vertex, but there is no change on viewport(screen) and if I try to use that vertex, it reverts back to its original value.

Note: I also used .updateMatrixWorld(); and .needsUpdate = true; but no luck.

Help me, please. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's hard to know without more code, but I see several possible problems.  The naming of `.fromBufferAttribute()` tells me that it creates a new object, so you're not modifying the initial vertex at all when you change that `.y` property.  Also, `.worldToLocal()` returns a new vector; it doesn't set the vector on the underlying `Object3D` at all.  If you want to change the vertex, you have to write that change into the buffer attribute; if you want to move `maleBody`, you have to change its `position` property.  Your code doesn't do those things.